# converting string to numbers and adding them to a list

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that takes numbers as string values,
then returns them as a number using yaml.load function, after that, the values should all be entered into a list which will be printed out.
This is the error I am getting.

> list = list.append(result)
>   AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
>   Blockquote

here is my code

```
_author__ = 'root'
```

"""
this program is to convert a string value to the integer equivalent using a function

"""

import yaml

def convertToString():

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    value = str(input('enter numbers within as a string'))
    result = yaml.load(value)
    lists = []
    lists = list.append(result)
    print(lists)
return result
```

convertToString()

And any other corrections are welcomed such as making sure that only strings are accepted as valid input.

Comment: did you ever read any documentation, where did you ever see a list created with  `{}`?

Comment: thanks for the correction, fixed that. Was able to solve the problem

Comment: don't use list as a variable name or your next question will be why does `list(...` not work

Answer (score 1):

replace  `list = {}`  to `your_list = []` or `your_list = list()`

Do not use `list` for a varable name as it was built-in type.

Answer (score 1):

`{ }` creates a dictionary, `()` creates a tuple. Use `[]`. However,If you have a list of string, you can make a list of int using `map`

```
lst = ["1","2","3"]
lst2 = map(int,lst)
print lst2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import yaml
```

def convertToString():

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    value = str(input('enter numbers within as a string'))
    result = yaml.load(value)
    list_type = [result]
    list_type = list_type.append(result)
    print(result)
return list_type
```

convertToString()

this works...will have to use exceptions to ensure that only strings are accepted as inputs. Thank you all.